# rails g bootstrap:install error on Rails 3.2.6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-rails

I can't find the answer I am looking, even though similar questions have been answered numerous times.

I get the error "Could not find generator bootstrap:install" when I run the rails command "rails g bootstrap:install".

I am using rails version 3.2.6 and all my other gems are update to date.

I checked my generators list and I don't see a "bootstrap" generator. I don't know where to go from here.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

You might want to run `bundle install` first, to make sure that the gem is installed.